# how to change the format of json value data in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to display data for a plugin with a predefined json format, but after I try the data does not match the format how the problem?

JSON Required

```
[
  {
    latLng: [-6.17343444,1206.834234294],
    name: 'XY'
  },
  {
    latLng: [-6.1742343244,106.898987294],
    name: 'XK'
  }
]
```

Result my JSON

```
[
  {
    "latLng": "-6.17343444,1206.834234294",
    "name": "XK"
  },
  {
    "latLng": "-6.1742343244,106.898987294",
    "name": "XY"
  }
]
```

myscript PHP

```
public function lat_lang() {
    foreach($this->model->name_model() as $row){    
        $data[] = array(
            'latLng' => $row->lat_long,
            'name' => $row->city
          );                                
    }
        header('content-type: application/json');   
        echo json_encode($data);    
}
```

call JSON

```
$.parseJSON('<?php echo base_url().'mycontrollers';?>', function(datas) {
    console.log(datas);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](https://php.net/explode) to transform the string `"-6.17343444,1206.834234294"` into an array `[-6.17343444,1206.834234294]`:

```
public function lat_lang() {
    foreach($this->model->name_model() as $row){    
        $data[] = array(
            'latLng' => explode(',',$row->lat_long),
            'name' => $row->city
          );                                
    }
        header('content-type: application/json');   
        echo json_encode($data);    
}
```

---

If you want to get floats (for all value in the JSON), you could use [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-numeric-check):

```
json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Or, just for a specific value:

```
$latLng = explode(',', $row->lat_long);
$latLng = array_map('floatval', $latLng);
$data[] = array(
    'latLng' => $latLng,
    'name' => $row->city
  );
```

Comment: thanks, @Syscall thanks, still unchanged, there are still quotes on json result
 `"latLng": ["-6.17343444", "1206.834234294"]`

Comment: @irwandwiyanto You can try `json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: @irwandwiyanto I've updated the answer with another way to force float value.